# Creating a user-defined function to loop a dilution experiment and make a large table from the results

Tags: r

I have two data sets, one is a table of gene expression of 20 genes (rows) for about 100 samples (columns).

Or simply:

```
              x1    x2    x3   ....
   gene1     1.2    1.4   1.5
   gene2     1.6    1.7   1.8
   ....
```

The other table has a different number of samples with the same number of rows (20).

I'm trying to create a new table that is a dilution between one chosen column of the first table with another chosen column of the second table,

```
percent_mix <- cbind(1.0, 0.90, 0.80, 0.70, 0.60, 0.50, 0.40, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10, 0)

rep.row<-function(x,n)
{
matrix(rep(x,each=n),nrow=n)
}

mixing_table <- rep.row(percent_mix, 20)

dilute <- function(x, y)
{
z1 <- x*mixing_table
z2 <- y*(1-mixing_table)
z1+z2
}

a <- dilute(table1[,1], table2[,1])
```

I want to make a loop so that I can dilute the first sample in table1 against all 12 samples in table2 and add all the results into one big table.

Then I need to do the exact same thing then to every column in table1 and add it onto the end that new big table.

I hope this makes sense. I'm looking to get one big table with every sample in table1 diluted against every sample in table2 and all the results in one final table.

Thanks for any tips!
g

Answer (score 0):

The example that you gave can be simplified to two lines of code:

```
pmix <- seq(1, 0, -0.1)
a <- outer(table1[, 1], pmix) + outer(table2[, 1], (1-pmix))
```

You can insert this into a double loop that will cycle through each column of `table1` paired with each column of `table2` like this:

```
results <- array(dim=c(20, 11, dim(table1)[[2]], dim(table2)[[2]]))
for(i in 1:dim(table1)[[2]]) {
for(j in 1:dim(table2)[[2]]) {
    results[, , i, j] <- outer(table1[, i], pmix) + outer(table2[, j], (1-pmix))
    }}
```

The result will be a four-dimensional array (basically, a matrix of matrices).